# Does George Lucas have a plan for how The Clone Wars series will continue into the movies?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

Is there a continuity plan to end *The Clone Wars* Series and tie it up to the movies?

As I imagine there are many unanswerable questions related to the star wars universe from the tv series.

Or is George Lucas just milking it as long as he can?

Comment: Lucas stated, years before _The Clone Wars_ hit TV that he had two TV shows based in the Star Wars universe that he was interested in producing and back then he stated about how long each could run.  I forgot the figures, but the live action one (which they've been planning) could, according to Lucas, run as long as 10 years.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no definite statements about how the current series will end, as (supervising director) Dave Filoni has mentioned how the story is constantly in flux and an ongoing writing process.

That said, they will indeed have to wrap up Ahsoka's arc (and there are many theories about this), but considering this takes place in the period between the second two prequel films, it would make sense for the series to wrap up on the eve of the space war over Coruscant (which was wonderfully dove-tailed into Genndy Tartakovsky's animated take on the saga).